# VSCode Custom Variables in Launch Settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to add custom variables that I can use in my `launch.json` settings for debugging in VSCode?  Currently, the only way I have found is to add them to my workspace settings and refer to the from the `${config}` [predefined variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

I'd like to define variables/properties in the `launch.json` and use them.  Here's an example of what that might look like if I wanted to add `myCustomVar` to all my URLs:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "myCustomVar": "my_value",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Page 1",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/page1.html?customVar=${myCustomVar}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "Page 2",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/page2.html?customVar=${myCustomVar}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dev"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) might work?

> Command variables are already powerful but they lack a mechanism to configure the command being run for a specific use case. For example, it is not possible to pass a **prompt message** or a **default value** to a generic "user input prompt".
>
> This limitation is solved with **input variables** which have the syntax: `${input:variableID}`. The `variableID` refers to entries in the inputs section of `launch.json` and `tasks.json`, where additional configuration attributes are specified. Nesting of input variables is not supported.
>
> The following example shows the overall structure of a `tasks.json` that makes use of input variables:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "version": "2.0.0",
>   "tasks": [
>     {
>       "label": "task name",
>       "command": "${input:variableID}"
>       // ...
>     }
>   ],
>   "inputs": [
>     {
>       "id": "variableID",
>       "type": "type of input variable"
>       // type specific configuration attributes
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Otherwise, you should be able to add custom settings to your VS Code settings.json file (it will warn you about "Unknown Configuration Setting") and insert them using `${config:myCustomVar}`.